# reduce system of differential equations to first order

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Given \begin{align*}
\begin{cases}y_1''(x)&=-x^2+y_1'(x)-y_2(x)^2\\
y_2''(x)&=y_2'(x)-y_1(x)^3 \end{cases}
\end{align*} with $y_1(0)=1=y_2'(0)$ and $y_2(0)=y_1'(0)=0$ I want to reduce this system to a system of first order.

So let $u_0=y_1$ and $u_1=y_1'$ and $v_0=y_2$ and $v_1=y_2'$ and we get

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\begin{pmatrix}u_0\\u_1\\v_0\\v_1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\-x^2+u_1-v_0^2\\v_1\\v_1-u_0^3
 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
0\\-x^2\\0\\0
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&1&-v_0&0\\0&0&0&1\\-u_0^2&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u_0\\u_1\\v_0\\v_1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

So my question is why don't get you get a matrix only filled with numbers? Or did I do anything wrong?

Comment: because your system is non-linear

Comment: @Norbert but the way I reduced it is right?

Comment: No, because $u_1'=-x^2+u_1+v_0^2$ and $v_1'=v_1-u_0^3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This matrix is non-constant because your original system is non-linear.

I fixed some typos in problem statement